# ObjectMapper cambia el nombre de los campos de mi clase

Tags: java

tengo una clase con un campo con 2 mayúsculas en el nombre, el cual sería este:

```
private String noCountName;
```

El problema es que con el `ObjectMapper` me está convirtiendo ese campo en `nocountName`, y eso me produce un error en este código:

```
    Class<?> clase = object.getClass();
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = obMapper.convertValue(object, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});

    for (Field field : clase.getDeclaredFields()) {
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        if(field.getType().equals(String.class) && objectMap.get(fieldName) == null) {
            objectMap.replace(field.getName(), "a");
        }
    }
```

En la línea `objectMap.replace(field.getName(), "a");`, el nombre que tiene el campo en el objectMapper es `nocountName` mientras que el `field.getName()` me devuelve el nombre correcto que es `noCountName`.

¿Alguno sabe a que se puede deber esto?